# sql site or book with exercise queries more complicated than www3.schools.com

Tags: sql-server

Hi
is there any online resource for practicing SQL queries more complicated ?
basically I had a db dev until now and I kind of forgot. I want to switch jobs and freshen up a little. 
They should more complicated than 2 joins or something, as my level is medium or senior hopefully :)
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bit dry, but if you're mid to senior level why not just look at the transact-sql reference on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx

Take a look at what's possible with the product, both the supporting examples and documentation are detailed and insightful. Many of the examples use the [AdventureWorks](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) sample database which you can download from codeplex

Answer (score 0):

[download SQL Server Express, it is free](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)

Then pick out one of the zillion SQL Server books available at amazon or any local bookstore.  There should be lots for every level of experience.  Then, work through the examples in that book.